# Is there such a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with a certain issu. How to check if there is a holomorphic, such that :

1. $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ on $\Delta(0,1)$
2. $f(\frac{3n}{3n+1})=0 $ on  $\Delta(0,2)$

Regarding the first example I thought to consider a function $f(x)=\sqrt{x} \  \text{where} \ x=\frac{1}{n}$. From continuity we have $f(0)=0$. Is the theorem of identify shows that such function exists?

Comment: What is $\Delta(0,1)$?

Comment: What is the "theorem of identify"? [Is that the correct name?]

Comment: No and no. In the first case the function has no derivative at 0. In the second, zeros of holographic function converge to 1 and from this is easy to deduct that the function must be 0. That is , in the second case only zero function satisfy the condition.

Comment: @leoli1 circle with center 0 and radius 1.

Comment: @coffeemath https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem